# OpenGL usampler2d value cannot be divided

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

I've been writing GLSL shaders, and using an integer texture (GL_RED) to store values in the shader.
When I attempt to divide a value taken from the usampler2D texture, it stays the same.
The following is the minimal reproducible shader.

```
#version 440

in vec2 uv;
out vec3 color;

layout (binding = 1) uniform usampler2D tm_data;

void main(){
  float index = texture(tm_data, uv).r;
  float divisor = 16.0f
  color = vec3(index / divisor, 0, 0);
}
```

The rendered red value is always 1.0 regardless of a way i try to divide or mutate the index value.

When the sampler is changed to a normalized one (sampler2D) the color manipulation works as expected

```
#version 440

in vec2 uv;
out vec3 color;

layout (binding = 1) uniform sampler2D tm_data; //Loads as normalized from [0,255] to [0,1]

void main(){
  float index = texture(tm_data, uv).r * 255.0f; //Convert back to integer approximation
  float divisor = 4.0f
  color = vec3(index / divisor, 0, 0); //Shade of red now appears considerably darker
}
```

Does anyone know why this unexpected behaviour happens?

The tm_data texture is loaded as GL_RED -> GL_RED
The OpenGL version used is 4.4
There is no framework being used (no sneaky additions), everything is loaded using gl function calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the use of `usampler2D`, the internal format has to be a unsigned integral format (e.g. `GL_R8UI`). See [Sampler types](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)#Sampler_types).
If the internal format is the basic format `GL_RED`, then the sampler type has to be `sampler2D`.
Note, `sampler*` is for the use of floating point formats, `isampler*` for signed integral formats and `usampler*` for unsigned integral formats.
See [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 4.1.7. Opaque Types](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#basic-types) and [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification - 8.9. Texture Functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.html#texture-functions)